# "To hump" in Russian (when referring to a dog)

Tags: перевод

Трахать is obviously not a good translation of "to hump" when describing what dogs do.  It's not a polite word and can't be used in print, wherеаs "to hump" is perfectly harmless and can be used by parents in front of kids, etc.  Is there a "nice" word for this in Russian?

***Edit***: All the translations suggested so far miss the fact that dogs hump outside of regular intercourse or mating.  So while it's possible to use a euphemism like "Он пристает к игрушкам," that doesn't come across as clearly as "He humps his toys" and many listeners might miss the meaning.

And what about "Doctor, he keeps humping my boyfriend's leg, it's so embarrassing"?  Humping is literally the act of thrusting the pelvis toward something, and it's puzzling that there isn't an equivalent *transitive* verb in Russian.  Especially since Russian dogs hump a lot more as neutering is not very popular there.

Comment: В деревнях, Псковской области говорят топчет. "Гляди! Ба! Петух снова чёрную топчет".

Comment: Трахать is *obviously* not a good translation!!

Comment: Петух топчет, не собака же.

Comment: Вяжутся is a proper harmless term but it can only applied to a pair of M+F dogs.

Answer (score 8):

I can't think of a Russian counterpart, and when it has to be polite, I'd use some euphemism like *пристраиваться* or *приставать*.

*Случаться*, *спариваться*, *делать садку* are, as Artemix noted, professional terms, and although they can be used harmlessly, they are really *to mate*, not *to hump*.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect the answers, thanks.

Comment: @KnocksX To the doctor I could say _он насилует мою ногу_. A little less nice, and with a hint of humor.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы использовал слово "оседлать":

```
Пёс опять сегодня оседлал плюшевого мишку
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest "кроет" or "покрывает".

Answer (score 2):

While researching the subject, I've found phrases крыть/покрывать/накрывать (colloquial), делать садку, and "подминать" (игрушки).  These are probably the closest true translations, even though they don't match "to hump" in popularity or usage.

The following euphemisms and phrases would also work to explain what's happening:

- направляет половое поведение (на...)
- возбуждается и плохо себя ведет
- выбирает объекты влечения

So much fuss over a funny four-letter word...

*Edit*: just noticed @Aksakal also suggested крыть/покрывать

Answer (score 2):

он удовлетворяется

> Шарик получал удовольствие от всего подряд, он удовлетворялся об игрушки, ноги, докторов.
>   Доктор с Шариком беда, он удовлетворяется обо все подряд, помогите ему доктор!

он ебёт:

> Шарик ебёт все подряд: игрушки, одежду, ноги. Особенно заводится с полосатого мишки, это его любимая игрушка.

I did't used doctor here, because that would be total special case.
Knocks X suggested *возбуждается и плохо себя ведет*, in proper context there no doubt what dog is doing.

So how it would be descried depends on: who will describe, situation context. Most (if not all) what someone can say about human intercourse, can be used in description of dog behavior. And vice versa.

Comment: The second quote is derogatory, and, actually straight-forward obscene (`мат`), so one should not typically use it in print.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate the verb "to hump" as "спариваться-спариться": It is a decent, harmless verb used with all animals when they do it.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen "пристраиваться" being used for the occasional dog-humping attempt.

I would personally use "приставать" for those dogs that are repeat offenders at humping *people*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word *покрывать* is a very close equivalent. Seems to be applicable to all four-legged animals. See [here](http://feb-web.ru/feb/ushakov/ush-abc/16/us350519.htm) and [here](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C).

*Пристраиваться* as suggested by [jwalker](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/4278/47) is another option, though the exact meaning may be unclear depending on the situation. *Пристроиться* may very well mean just a cosy comfortable position. To achieve the sexual connotation, one would have to make sure to use it with *к* (to emphasize the direction) rather than *на*, *у* (location). So:

> пристроиться к его ноге

rather than

> пристроиться у его ноги.

The reason why there is no clarity in this topic is probably that all sex-related topics in general have long been a taboo in the USSR. The same explains why the words used to describe sex to a large extent belong to profanity in Russian.

Answer (score -1):

**Чпокать** — to do someone

**Чпокаться** — to do together

**Чпокаются** — they do

From word "**чпок**", it when pull out your finger out of your mouth pulling cheek. Distinctive sound. Sounds like when penis in vagina or "fap". Funny word.
Don't know how it sounds in english.
Not serious, but the best thing I thought up.

Comment: Вообще-то вопрос о "характерных движениях тазом", так что звука как такового не происходит (особенно приставание к игрушкам или к ноге бойфренда).